# SharePoint 2010 custom list view returning items in the list according to criteria

Tags: list, view, sharepoint-2010

i am new to sharepoint 2010 and was wondering if it is possible to create a view for a list that would return specific items.

Let's say the items in the list have a column called status and i want to show only items with status="pending" in the custom view.  is that possible?

Comment: Even without programming. This can be done by setting a filter on your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a content query webpart, see: http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2009/11/17/content-query-web-part-on-sharepoint-2010-supports-multi-value-lookup-fields.aspx